# Why do I have invalid syntax in default pygame.py?

Tags: python, pygame

Always, when I want to use Python framework `pygame` and I want to compile it, it's printing this:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hanisek/game.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/home/hanisek/pygame.py", line 3
    03f3 0d0a 5fff 9355 6300 0000 0000 0000
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not importing `pygame` the framework, you are importing `pygame.py`, a file in the same directory:

```
    import pygame
  File "/home/hanisek/pygame.py", line 3
```

Remove or rename that file.

Comment: It's interesting. I installed pygame, but.. It didn't work.. I reinstalled it, removed pygame.py and it actually work!